# How to change ad maxCPC in Google AdWords campaign through API

Tags: c#, .net, google-ads-api

I'm new in Google AdWords api, and I'm wondering how to change CPC on advertisements. Please don't judge me strict. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this code to change Ad State, but I think CPC changes in the same way.

```
// Get the CampaignService.
AdGroupAdService adService = (AdGroupAdService)user
       .GetService(Google.Api.Ads.AdWords
       .Lib.AdWordsService.v201406.AdGroupAdService);
List<AdGroupAdOperation> operations = new List<AdGroupAdOperation>();
AdGroupAd targetAd = new AdGroupAd
{
    adGroupId = ad.GroupId,
    ad = new Ad { id = ad.Id },
    tatus = ad.IsActive ? AdGroupAdStatus.ENABLED: AdGroupAdStatus.PAUSED
};
AdGroupAdOperation co = new AdGroupAdOperation
{
    @operator = Operator.SET,
    operand = targetAd
};
operations.Add(ad);
adService.mutate(operations.ToArray());
```

I used [this](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/clientlibraries) helpful client libraries.